# Calculate time difference using TimeSpan

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datetime, timespan

I am trying to calculate the time difference of two given times slots but the answers does not seem to be correct what am I doing wrong?

My code:
[image]

For some reason the value given `amFinish` is changed from 16:30 to 16:18:00 I have no idea why!

And What if I have a text box and the user enters 16.30 how would I take that value and compute it as 16hrs and 30mins

The answer should be 05.30 but instead I get 05.18. Any sugestions?

Comment: You do realize that amStart is in minutes so you are subtracting (11 minutes - 16 hours and 18 minutes) and shouldn't you subtract amFinish - amStart anyway? If you are are wanting 5:30 try (new TimeSpan(16,30,00)  - new TimeSpan(11,00,00));

Answer (score 9, accepted):

30% of an hour is 18 minutes.

16.30 hours is 16 hours and 30/100 parts of an hour.

16 hours and a half would be 16.50.

Comment: OK got it thanks. What if I have a text box and the user enters 16.30 how would I take that value and compute it as 16.5?

Comment: +1. @Tacit, it is much easier and safe to reject such value instead of guessing if user wanted 0.3 or 0.5, or equally other way around does 0.50 means 50 minutes or 30 minutes? Just simply say no.

Comment: I'm sure there's away to do it. Well in my case I have a number of time slots and I need to calculate the time difference of all as i go along adding the previous time difference to the new time difference which that could contain a .30

Comment: @Tacit you can split the string on `.` - create two timespans. One from the hours and one from the minutes and add them together.

Answer (score 1):

You have decimal `16.3` hours, which is 16 hours and 18 minutes as Oded explains.

If you need to specify both hours, minutes, and seconds, use the overload of the `TimeSpan` constructor which takes three arguments:

```
TimeSpan amStart = new TimeSpan(0, 11, 0);
TimeSpan amFinish = new TimeSpan(16, 30, 0);
```

And if you need to convert a `string` into a `TimeSpan`, use something like:

```
TimeSpan amFinish = TimeSpan.ParseExact("16.30", @"hh\.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: this gives me 00.05 as the answer